# "SystemStackError in PinsController#index" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pins

I'm Working in OneMonth Rails, I mistakenly deleted a user pin with an id of 6 inside of the console. Now I'm unable to create a new pin on local host. How can I fix the "SystemStackError in PinsController#index" error that I'm receiving?

index.html.erb:

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-title">

<h1>Listing Pins</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= image_tag pin.image.url(:medium) %></td>
        <td><%= pin.description %></td>
        <td><%= pin.user.email if pin.user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', pin %></td>
        <% if pin.user == current_user %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to 'New Pin', new_pin_path %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the code that I've written in the new action within my pins_controller.rb file.

```
def new
  @pin = current_user.pins.build
end
```

Here is the server log:

```
    Started GET "/pins" for ::1 at 2016-04-25 14:49:20 -0500
Processing by PinsController#index as HTML
  [1m[36mPin Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "pins".* FROM "pins"[0m
  Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:79


  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (79.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (84.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (173.0ms)
```

[Here is an image of the error I'm receiving from your last comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ7sP.png)

Below is my pins_controller.rb file:

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(id: params[:id])
    end

    def current_user
       @pins = current_user.pins.find_by(params[:id])
       redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if @pin.nil? 
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
    end
  end
```

Comment: What code you have written in `new` action

Comment: @7urkm3n I've updated my question to include my index.html.erb file. Thx.

Comment: @7urkm3n I believe this was cause by me deleting the user id=6 in the console. Before that, I was able to upload pin images along with descriptions.

Comment: @freshmurry sorry i couldnt fix it, no idea its like module issue. I never seen  in my life smth like that.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `new` method, Its supposed to be like this.

```
def new
  @pin = Pin.new
end

def create
  @pin = current_user.pins.build(YOUR PARAMS HERE)
end
```

Comment: No it didn't work... I believe the problem lies in the fact that I was trying to delete a pins id=6 in the console and now I get an error message that says "SystemStackError in PinsController#index" and "stack level too deep."

Comment: I'm sorry, which folder can I find that inside? You can reference my code at github.com/freshmurry/pintresting

Comment: You can view the server log above.

Comment: It's taking all day to load in localhost. I'll update you on the status momentarily.

Comment: I've added an image of the error. Is there another work-around?